# Magento group prices for simple products associated with configurable products

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, product

I would like to know if it's possible in magento 1.8.0 to show different group prices for a simple product that is part of a configurable product.

I have a configurable product (T-shirt) and i have 5 simple products (for 5 different colors) that are associated with the configurable product.

When i create group prices for the configurable product they do show on the frontend.

But how do i proceed if, for example, the red t-shirt costs more than the blue one?

In the admin panel I can save different group prices for each simple product, but they don't show up on the website.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, my problem is the same. have you solved in such way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not following your question**, but it should be a case of setting the `Super product attributes configuration` of the `Associated Products` of the `Configured Product`.

So if the red t-shirt is an extra 10, then put 10 next to that option for the color attribute. (In the bit so it looks like 'Price: 10 Fixed' ). Does that make sense? Can you follow which part of the Magento Admin area I mean? It is Catalog->Manage Products->[edit your configured product]->Associatated Products->Super product attributes configuration->Color->Option:Red Price:10

Remember to save the product and then on the front end of your site in the drop down of colour options for the T-shirts you should see 'Red +10' displayed. You might need to refresh some caches.

**EDIT following comment below:

Then I think what you are trying to do is non-standard so it would need a third party module or custom coding.

One other suggestion: you might try creating bundle products instead of configurable products - on the front end the bundle options will pull through the group price of the simple product.

Have you looked at this module *[Customer Group Prices for Magento](http://www.webtexsoftware.com/customer-group-prices-magento-extension)* by Webtex? I haven't used it.

If you are planning to code something yourself let me know and I will change my answer above but I don't have a full answer for custom coding this and I don't think it will be trivial because it sounds like you want customer group level control of the `Super product attributes configuration` of the `Associated products` of a `configurable product` type, yes? If you are looking for code tips please edit your question to list explicitly the simple product prices and your customer groups - maybe an example price/group matrix so that stackoverflow readers can understand your required product price logic.

Maybe there is another way to organize your products like using multiple stores, multiple websites or trying bundles.

Comment: I'm aware of this option. But my question is how to manage this extra price for each customer group individually.